# Authorization of access to resources with spring security and Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I made permission to access resources in spring security as shown in this code: "The user authentication is then from the DB"

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
     @Autowired
     protected void globalConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
     //auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER");
         auth.jdbcAuthentication()
             .dataSource(dataSource)
             .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal, password as credentials, etat as actived from utilisateurs where username=?")
             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username as principal, ur.nom_role as role from utilisateurs u inner join roles ur on(u.roles_id=ur.id_role) where u.username=?")
             .rolePrefix("ROLE_");
     }

 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
         .csrf().disable()
           .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(100).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false).expiredUrl("/Login");
          http
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/AppJS/**","/images/**","/pdf/**","/Template/**","/Views/**","/MainApp.js").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/Users/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
           .antMatchers("/Dashbord/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
           .antMatchers("/Login*").anonymous()
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
         .formLogin().loginPage("/Login").permitAll()
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
           .failureUrl("/Login?error=true")
           .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
           .and()
         .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll()
           .logoutSuccessUrl("/Login");


     }

}
```

Subsequently, I specified the views for each URL:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addViewController("/Login").setViewName("Login");
       registry.addViewController("/Dashbord").setViewName("home");
       registry.addViewController("/logout").setViewName("Login");
       registry.addViewController("/Users").setViewName("Views/ListUsers");
    }
}
```

I used the angularJS routeProvider to keep track of URLs:

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file-model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Users', {
                controller:'UsersController', 
                templateUrl: 'Views/ListUsers'
        })     
      .when('/Dashbord', {
              controller: 'ResultController',
             templateUrl: 'Views/home.html'
        });  
});
```

> My problem is how to make the link of the access authorization that I
>   defined in spring security with the URLs of angularjs ($
>   routeProvider)

Thank you,
and Have a good day,

Comment: There are lots of tutorials around regarding user authorization in single page apps. Study them first. Question is far too broad as there are major differences to what you have already started

Answer (score 0):

You could try enable `html5mode`, to get this

`AngularJS: http://localhost:8080/Users`

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
    .when('/Users', {
            controller:'UsersController', 
            templateUrl: 'Views/ListUsers'
    })     
  .when('/Dashbord', {
          controller: 'ResultController',
         templateUrl: 'Views/home.html'
    });  

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
});
```

Comment: This is completely misleading OP into believing a simple change can be made when they have a fundamental misunderstanding on the whole process of security in an SPA

Comment: Note that this will provide **zero** protection when user switches angular routes and answer does nothing to explain how the client side authorization would work

Comment: @leguest Thank you for your answer. He sort of solved the problem. But when I specify the url in the tag "a" (<a href="/Users"> Users </a>) it redirects to "**http: // localhost: 8080 / Users**" but I must have this Url "**http: // localhost: 8080 / App / Users**"                                              You have an explanatory tutorial to ensure authorization and security of users

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will meets your requirement but yes i have already did before with the use of `ngPermission`. Before that you need list of the roles to set in your route.

```
.state('view1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl',
        resolve: {
            authorization: ["ngPermissionService", function (ngPermissionService) {

                //you need to call webserivce at this level for get all user's permissions and return it.

                return ngPermissionService.role(["admin"])  

            }]
        }
    });
```

For more details [click here](http://tushariscoolster.github.io/ngPermission/)

Comment: Thank you, I try not to authorize access with angularJs but rather with spring security is better. I only allow users who have the admin role to do the management of the users through the url "/ Users" which is defined in spring security. So can I define this in angularjs?

Comment: As per @leguest, he is right and we can do as per his instruction by enable html5mode, try it